# chrome extension onMessageExternal not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "sth",
    "description": "sth",
    "version": "0.1",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "externally_connectable": {
        "ids": [
            "mmaocogodokhpkellandkpdknpnihple"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "https://*.google.de/*"
        ],
        "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    return true;
});
```

content.js

```
console.log("content");
var msg = { text: "test" };
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("mmaocogodokhpkellandkpdknpnihple", msg, function() {
    console.log("content callback");
});
```

When on https://www.googel.de I click on the icon and see "content" and "content callback"in the console, but the request isn't logged in the console of the background-script. I probably miss something here... ?

(Chrome 44 on Linux)

Comment: check the main window console. Thats where content.js console logs information.

Comment: Why do you specify both `ids` and `matches`? Doesn't make any sense. Also it's not clear whether `externally_connectable` is necessary, maybe you can do it via normal extension messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm It makes sense. It allows both. However, allowing it for own id doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages inside your own extension are not external. You need the regular, boring messages with `onMessage` and without specifying the ID.

```
// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content.js"});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    return true; // Why? This keeps the communication channel open waiting,
                 // and then you won't see "content callback"
});
```

.

```
// content.js
console.log("content");
var msg = { text: "test" };
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function() {
    console.log("content callback");
});
```

Indeed, maybe returning `true` got you confused? It's needed when you plan to call `sendResponse` asynchronously, and so the callback of `sendMessage` won't fire until you do.

Comment: Thanks Xan. I tried onMessage first with no luck, which lead me to think External would do the trick. Can't retrace what I did wrong in first place, but it works now.